# Delphi iOS Simulator error message 'Session ended'

Tags: ios, delphi, simulator

I am trying to run iOS Simulator from Delphi having setup the following needed configurations:

1. I am using mac with Parallel Desktop for my RAD Studio virtual machine.
2. I am using Delphi 10.1 Berlin.
3. Already installed an XCode and running.
4. I have my command line tools.
5. I have platform assistant and running in my mac.
6. I already created my connection profile using the IPAddress and port given by PAServer.
7. Installed SDK for OSX and iOS in the SDK Manager.

I have no problem running my OSX on my Mac.

The only issue I have is my iOS Simulator is not working. Here'sscreenshot of the error message.

[image: iOS Simulator error message]

I swear I checked the recommended troubleshoot procedures several times but no avail.

I hope someone help me get through with this. I already spent the whole day searching/troubleshooting this connection.

Many thanks and cheers!

Comment: Try to run the simulator on Mac before deployment. After the error, go to the mac and check if your app is available in the simulator. Run it by hand. Try it in release mode first, without debugging.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Hotfix for 10.1 Berlin called "30680_rad_studio_10.1_berlin_hotfix_11_jan_2017". It should be available for download from your EDN account under "My registered user downloads".

You need to copy the files from this zip archive onto your Mac in the PAServer-18.0 application folder `/Applications/PAServer-18.0.app/Contents/MacOS`. There is a `readme_en.txt` with a detailed description.

Comment: @G_Wimpassinger thanks for sharing me this. Greatly appreciated.